# change Python plot x axis sticker values

Tags: python, plot

I have a sequence of 24 values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = range(0,24)

plt.plot(y,marker='*',linestyle='--',color='b',label='y value')
```

by default, x axis value start from 0 until 24. How can I reset the x axis values?

so that x axis values are  in the order of   range(8,24) + range(0,8), I don't want y values change, just reset the x axis to 8....,23,0,...7

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want correctly, add the following line before your call to `plt.plot`:

```
plt.xticks(range(0, 24), range(8, 24) + range(0, 8))
```

The first argument specifies where you want your new labels to be, and the second argument is simply the range you specified, as labels.